# cv.glmnet Ridge Regression lambda.min = lambda.1se?

Tags: r, cross-validation, ridge-regression, glmnet

I'm currently running a ridge regression in R using the `glmnet` package, however, I recently ran into a new problem and was hoping for some help in interpreting my results. My data can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/hpxu3t0vqkrzfgf/AAB6F-yMYMfuI5E__gfDuW6sa?dl=0

My data consists of a 26531x428 observation matrix `x` and a 26531x1 response vector `y`. I am attempting to determine the optimal value of `lambda.min`, and when I run the code

`> lambda=cv.glmnet(x=x,y=y,weights=weights,alpha=0,nfolds=10,standardize=FALSE)`

I get

`$lambda.min
[1] 2.123479
$lambda.1se
[1] 619.0054`

which are results I would expect. However, I would like to add a slight tweak to this regression. I have prior knowledge of each of my 428 coefficients, and instead of shrinking each coefficient towards 0, as is the default with ridge regression, I would like to shrink each coefficient towards a specific value other than 0. After reaching out to Dr. Trevor Hastie, one of the creators of `glmnet`, he told me that this could be achieved by running the same code after substituting `y` with `y2`, where `y2 = y - x%*%d` and `d` is a 428x1 vector of coefficient priors. He said to then add `d` to my new coefficients, which would give me my prior-informed coefficients. After rerunning the code

`> lambda=cv.glmnet(x=x,y=y2,weights=weights,alpha=0,nfolds=10,standardize=FALSE)`

I unfortunately get

`$lambda.min
[1] 220.3026
$lambda.1se
[1] 220.3026`

The results of `plot(lambda)` look like this
[image: lambda plot]

Does anyone know why `glmnet` can't find a suitable `lambda.min`? Could it be because my vector of priors contains estimates that are too far off? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Glmnet is returning a very large optimal regularization parameter, i.e., it is regularizing away all of your coefficients.  It looks like glmnet is telling you that, after accounting for your prior (or offset) coefficients, what is left is noise.  That is, you already offset the correct coefficients, and the model is just validating that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So, if I understand you correctly, does that mean I should be ok using the coefficient estimates from the prior as my coefficients and ignore the glmnet results altogether?

Comment: It looks to me from that plot that the coefficients from glmnet (at the optimal lambda) should be all zero, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, the coefficients at lambda.min are all zero, so when I add that coefficient vector to the prior coefficient vector, it obviously is just the prior coefficient vector. Does that change your interpretation of the results at all?

Comment: No, I just asked that to validate and double check.  So yah, I think our interpretation is solid then: you've validated that your prior coefficient vector is, as far as glmnet can tell, completely correct.